# Распределить два массива по таблице

Tags: html, python, django

Необходимо распределить два массива по таблице, каждый в своём столбце. Понимаю, что вопрос очень глупый и простой, но никак не могу справиться с этим :( Заранее спасибо!

```
<table class="table table-striped" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Site Title</th>
                <th>Url</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for q in q %}
            {% for z in z %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="counterCell"></td>
                    <td>{{q}}</td>
                    <td>{{z}}</td>
                </tr>

            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Результат (таблица):**

Los Angeles Times | www.latimes.com

Los Angeles Times | www.bbc.com

Los Angeles Times | www.abcnews.go.com

BBC | www.latimes.com

BBC | www.bbc.com

BBC | www.abcnews.go.com

ABC News |  www.latimes.com

ABC News |  www.bbc.com

ABC News |  www.abcnews.go.com

**Нужно:**

Los Angeles Times | www.latimes.com

BBC |   www.bbc.com

ABC News |  www.abcnews.go.com

**ОБНОВЛЕНО:**

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor1 = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT sites.site_title, sites.url FROM sites, my_sites, auth_user WHERE auth_user.id = my_sites.id_user AND sites.id = my_sites.id_site AND auth_user.id ="+str(request.user.id))
cursor1.execute("SELECT sites.site_title, sites.url FROM sites, my_sites, auth_user WHERE auth_user.id = my_sites.id_user AND sites.id = my_sites.id_site AND auth_user.id ="+str(request.user.id))

q = [str(row[0]) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
z = [str(row[1]) for row in cursor1.fetchall()]
#print(q)
#print(z)
#print(q+z)
a = [(q,z)]
print(a)
return render(request, 'main/my_newsagent.html', {'q': q, 'z': z})
```

**Результат:**
[(['Los Angeles Times', 'BBC', 'ABC News'], ['www.latimes.com', 'www.bbc.com', 'www.abcnews.go.com'])]

Comment: В вашей функции во views.py создайте, например, список кортежей и передавайте в шаблон его, а не 2 отдельных списка. `[("Los Angeles Times | www.latimes.com", "BBC | www.bbc.com"), (и т.д.)]`

Comment: не понятно почему нельзя сделать что название и сайт были в одной модели и выводить их в таблицы

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin я делаю запрос к базе данных

Comment: я думаю лучше скинуть код с views.py чтобы вам смогли помочь

Comment: @AlioshcaZ, а вы мне случайно не подскажете, как это сделать?:) У меня получается немного не такой массив, который нужен... я обновила вопрос

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin обновила вопрос)

Comment: Если я правильно понял результат запроса к БД, то смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Типо того попробуйте:

**views.py**

```
q = [str(row[0]) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
z = [str(row[1]) for row in cursor1.fetchall()]
qz = [(q[i], z[i]) for i in range(len(q))]
return render(request, 'main/my_newsagent.html', {'qz': qz})
```

**my_newsagent.html**

```
<tbody>
    {% for element in qz %}
        <tr>
            <td class="counterCell"></td>
            <td>{{ element.0 }}</td>
            <td>{{ element.1 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, очень помогли!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад, что работает)